# Laravel - request in controller is empty after redirect in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

When i redirect a route, Can't access to request data.

This is the ajax request informations:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
param1=my+param&request=search
```

**routes.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::any('/items/search', 'ItemsController@search');

Route::any('/items', [ 
    function(Request $request){

        if ($request->input('request') == 'search') {
            // echo $request->input('param1');  // returns param1 value correctly
            return redirect()->action('ItemsController@search')->withInput();
        }
    }
]);
```

And this is **controller**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class ItemsController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->all()); // returns: array(0) { }
    }
}
```

How can i access post data in controller, after redirect?

Comment: Just moved the logic to controller and i don't need redirect anymore. Thanks to Mike.

Answer (score 1):

The method `withInput` adds the input to the Session. You can access it in the controller using `$request->session->all()`.

That being said, a more RESTful way to do it is to have one route `/items` and in your controller you decide whether to filter results based on input parameters or not.

Comment: `$request->session->all()` returns `Call to a member function all() on a non-object`

Comment: Ok, I'll move the logic to controller totally. Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this in the controller? [See here for usage](http://laravel.com/docs/master/session#basic-usage)

Comment: Yes. It's inside controller. Maybe needs a import or `use`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return redirect()->route('/items/search')->withInput();
```

Comment: Tried this before. Throws an error: `InvalidArgumentException inrlGenerator.php line 278: Route [/items/search] not defined.` I know, This is weird :/